# How to mask a folder name differently to WSL?

Tags: mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ln, mklink

I am using Microsoft's OneDrive for Business provided by our university to sync big junks of data. I'm also using using a software to run some simulations which is not available for windows and I have to use WSL. Now the issue is that OneDrive folder name is like `OneDrive - University of foobar` and the software I'm using refuses to accept path names with spaces in it. Unfortunately as far as I know Microsoft has made it impossible to change the folder name for OneDrive for business. I have to find a way to fool WSL to think the folder name is different. something without spaces!

What I have tried:

- I have tried `ln -s link target` but when running the software it considers the original folder
- I have tried `mount --bind link target` but it behaves weirdly and I didn't get what I needed
- I also tried the windows side using `mklink /D link target` it did not work either.

I would appreciate if you could help me know if there are any solutions to let the WSL see the folder name differently.

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong solution**

Thanks to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/9et49i/how_to_mask_a_folder_name_differently_to_windows/e5rkr4f) on Reddit I was able to solve this issue. I was using `ln` in a wrong way. The correct form is:

```
ln -s /target/path/with\ spaces/ /path/to/link/file
```

where `file` must not exist beforehand. Now WSL treats `file` as the target folder!